# Fetch api data according to project status in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to fetch data according to project status in Flutter

I want to fetch data according to project status

{

"status": true,

"data": [

```
{
```

"Project_status": "Closed",
"
"jobs": {

```
"Title": "Project Manager",
                      
                      }

   },

  {
```

"Project_status": "in_Progress",
"jobs": {

"Title": "Data Analyst",

```
        }

}
```

]
}